# How can i use UserId field on AWS SNS?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I'm developing my own app that use SNS+GCM for push notifications.
Is there a way to notify devices by UserId and not with the device-token?

Comment: No.  The only way that GCM can know **where** to deliver the notification is through the device ID.

Comment: Yes i know, but i want to notify SNS with the UserId and then SNS will notify GCM with device-token.

Comment: I see, sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: Please read doc here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html and http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/SNS/latest/sns-dg.pdf

Answer (score 2):

`UserId` - is reserved property for Baidy provider.

*When using CreatePlatformEndpoint with Baidu, two attributes must be provided: ChannelId and UserId. The token field must also contain the ChannelId*

See more here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_CreatePlatformEndpoint.html

---

But in my project I use `UserId` property to store mappings between user in my db and endpoints on SNS side. I have same mapping in db, but having `UserId` inside SNS UI make debug easier.